# Retrieve fans name/country using GRAPH API

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I can get fan counts of my page using graph api. But how to retrieve their names and
 country. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
<body>
<a>
   <img src="cover.jpg"><br><br><br>
</a>
</br>

<?php

$json_url='https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT uid FROM page_fan
WHERE page_id=617384194943403&
access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAOo5ZC6CkvxYX7VYy1Gph9YaCVc6MLRIWZB4xyT4z8l9L1giBMhmd6grSeil
3O5fCOOTUofEPGyGYh1Nd1ogljZACUsSehkE8ZCUwDZBZCXmrsaFXJh0aRtUJvTfzzo0ZCc2zaeZCBu5hnlWV1
waorBhGdKAhhS9gQofYmANZCRy6K3oL0HmRFtQZD'; 
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_output = json_decode($json);
$likes = 0;
if($json_output->likes){
$likes = $json_output->likes;
}

?> 

<h3><font size=+3> 
<?php
  echo 'Number of likes for Facebook Page ='.$json_url;
 ?> 
  </font> </h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you try the solution? Have you already solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's very straight forward.

Since, you are able to retrieve the **uids**  for the users, you can make another API call using fql query `SELECT name, current_location FROM user WHERE uid=user_id_here` for each uid that you've retrieved.

This will give you the user's full name and user's current location (from which you can extract user's country).